# Force Refresh on Dialog before showing it with react-native-dialog-component

Tags: react-native, dialog

I am using https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-dialog-component for my Dialogs and I am having some problems with async functions not refreshing the dialog. I am using it like in the example with

```
 render() {
    return (
        ...
        <Button onItemPressed={(item) => {
                    this.completeMovementDialog.show()
                }}/>}
        ...
        <CompleteMovementDialog onRefresh={() => this.getStationsNearToPlayer()}
                        ref={(completeMovementDialog) => {
                                this.completeMovementDialog = completeMovementDialog;
                            }}/>
```

The CompleteMovementDialog uses the onRefresh Method in `componentDidMount()` and is a wrapper for a `DialogComponent`. It works fine, when i refresh the list, that is retrieved from the backend by `this.getStationsNearToPlayer()`. The problem is, that the `CompleteMovementDialog` component gets loaded, as soon as the component around it gets loaded. So when i call `this.startMovementDialog.show()` it does not go into `componentDidMount` anymore and the list is never refreshed unless you refresh it manually. Does anybody have a tip, how i can achieve to forecefully refresh the list before `show()`? Or is there a better library to show dialogs? I heard `ref` is not a good practice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody stumbling across this:

The `DialogComponent` offers a `onShown` and `onDismissed` property, where you can pass a function, that can be an api call. I solved it by loading the data in the `onShown` callback and set the view to loading mode again, when the dialog was dismissed and the `onDismissed` callback occured.